# Mysql greater threads running

Tags: linux, networking, mysql, rds, mysql5.7

I have my Mysql DB instance in RDS, My CPU is jumping from 50% to 100%.. Later i checked my DB threads..

I was surprised with my thread count.

```
 SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name =
 "Connections"
```

The output for the above query as follow

```
Threads connected 21
Threads created 1642
Threads running 18446744073709515083
```

What is happening here..! Any help appreciated..

Also attached image for your ref

[image]

Comment: Please post results of SELECT @@version;  You are probably looking at needing to post a 'bug report'.  It is unlikely in your lifetime you will see a CPU with enough TB of RAM to support this count of Threads running.  Maybe this would work better for you, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE 'Threads_%' OR variable_name = 'Connections';

Comment: 5.7.12-log  -- version.. Added the image

Comment: Your 5.7.12 became General Availability 2016-04-11.  Newer changelogs do not mention threads_running that included looking through 5.7.27 which became GA on 2019-07-22.  With 26087 Connections, you have an obviously busy system.  My next comment will request additional information to allow workload analysis.  This specific question about Threads_running with such a large count should be reported as a bug, in my opinion.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you could post requested information, will provide some tips for improving performance of your instance.

Answer (score 2):

18446744073709515083 -- Sounds like the actual number is -1 (or some other slightly negative number).  This would be a fluke, possibly caused by some threads going away while your `SHOW STATUS` was running.  Try simply `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running'`.

What version of MySQL are you using?  Some major changes happened in 8.0.  If that is the version, please file a bug report ( bugs.mysql.com ).

Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see what queries are running.  Ignore the "Sleep" ones.  Check out the ones with large "Time".

High CPU usually comes from an inefficient `SELECT`.  Find it, then show us `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Sound good.. I contacted the AWS team, They had some bugs in the Aurora engine version 2.04.5, I updated the Aurora version to 2.07 the issue is fixed now..Also the DB CPU is still going high even for lower number of users,

Comment: Is there any 3rd party tools to check the inefficient queries..and montior the DB effectively

Comment: @ManikandanRam - I like the slowlog for finding inefficient queries.

Comment: Sometimes under loaded conditions,Chances were there for normal optimal queries to be listed under slow query..! In that situations what can we do

Comment: @ManikandanRam - Certain settings lead to unnecessary entries, see this for my recommendations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: @ManikandanRam - Also, use `pt-query-digest` (as mentioned there) to summarize the log, thereby making it easier to ignore the noise.

Comment: Interesting, Let me go through the docx